# Attach_field_load() drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created some fields in drupal 7 in create user administration. I want those fields in my custom form in my custom module in drupal 7.

I am not sure but this function attach_field_load() will do the trick. If someone can help.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `attach_field_load()` function to the best of my knowledge, you're probably looking for [`field_attach_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7):

```
function MYMODULE_my_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state);
}
```

Comment: ohh yeah sory, my bad . Function is http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: That's not the right function to use, the correct one is the one stated in the answer (`field_attach_form()`)

Comment: thank you clive. But its returning the whole form instead I want the each field to handle my self in my custom form. 

Regards

Comment: That's going to be quite tricky, you might be better off using `field_attach_form` and then looping through the `$form` variable to make changes/remove items you don't want instead of trying to build it up for individual fields

Answer (score 2):

As of Drupal 7.22 you can simply use the following code to add a single field to your form.

`field_attach_form('my_entity_type', $entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => 'field_myfield'));`

See https://drupal.org/node/1825844